# Operation of whether there is form field or there is no form field in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

FormType

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        $builder->add('status', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => array(
                'A' => 'A',
                'B' => 'B',
                'C' => 'C',
            ),
            'required' => true
        ));

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

View : This is no problem.

```
{{ form_widget(form.status) }}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

View : Problem is this case.

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
    {{ form_widget(form.status) }}
{% endif %}
{{ form_widget(form.name) }}
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
```

It has register blank status value if not login.
MY intention is to no change status value if there is no status field.

Do I have to switch another "FormType" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the role in the form builder too, and you have 2 solutions to do that.

**Solution 1**

The most elegant is to create a custom form type as a service, depending on the security context:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    private $securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');

        // If the user is granted
        if($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))
        {
            $builder->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'A' => 'A',
                    'B' => 'B',
                    'C' => 'C',
                ),
                'required' => true
            ));
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Mark the form type as a service :

```
services:
    form.type.article:
        class: Foo\BarBundle\Form\Type\ArticleType
        arguments: ["@security.context"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: article_type }
```

Now, instead of calling `new ArticleType()` in your controller, call this new service :

```
$form = $this->createForm($this->get('form.type.article'), $data);
```

**Solution 2**

The second solution is to pass the security context to the `ArticleType`, no need to create a service. In your controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')), $article);
```

And in your form type :

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    private $isGranted;

    public function __construct($isGranted)
    {
        $this->isGranted = $isGranted;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');

        // If the user is granted
        if($this->isGranted)
        {
            $builder->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'A' => 'A',
                    'B' => 'B',
                    'C' => 'C',
                ),
                'required' => true
            ));
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Because it is a little more complex conditional branch in fact, I try to apply the solution 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below.

Change your FormType class to:

```
class ArticleType extends AbstractType
{
    private $isRemembered;

    protected function __construct($isRemembered) {
        $this->isRemembered = $isRemembered;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text');
        if($this->isRemembered) {
            $builder->add('status', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => array(
                    'A' => 'A',
                    'B' => 'B',
                    'C' => 'C',
                ),
                'required' => true
            ));
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

And in the controller where you are instantiating the form type,

```
$isRemembered = $this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED');
$form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType($isRemembered), $entity);
```

and remove the condition check in twig file.

Comment: Thank you. Because it is a little more complex conditional branch in fact, I try to apply the solution.